# Search for similar products quoted by Different vendors and get cheapest in order_line

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am using Odoo and python.

I am trying to search for similar products in "purchase.order.line" quoted by different vendors and then get the cheapest vendor.

Below are the pics:

[Vendor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho5KO.jpg)

[Vendor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZ1R.jpg)

The upper section is class **PurchaseOrder**
and where there is Products and price is class **PurchaseOrderLine**

The below code is what I was trying to do for the cheapest product in the second class "purchase.order.line".

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'purchase.order'
 supplier_prequalification_id = fields.Many2one("supplier.prequalification", string="Supplier Prequalification")

class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
 supplier_prequalification_id = fields.Many2one("supplier.prequalification", related="order_id.supplier_prequalification_id", string="Supplier Prequalification", store=True)
 cheapest = fields.Boolean(string="Cheapest Price", compute="compute_cheapest")
 vendor = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Vendor", related="partner_id", store=True)
 count = fields.Float()

def compute_cheapest(self):
for rec in self:
    partner = rec.env['purchase.order'].search([('partner_id', '=', rec.partner_id.id)])
    for each_partner in partner:
        line = each_partner.order_line
        for item in line:
            if item.product_id.__________:
              item.count = min(item.price_unit)

              if item.count:
                item.write({'cheapest': True})
              else:
                item.write({'cheapest': False})
```

The place where I have put the dash is where I am stuck. How can I search in every vendor's oder_line and find similar products quoted by them. The cheapest price for that product I can store it on count float and then if count I do the last code of selecting boolean true.
Doesn't have to store cheapest on count. We can just say cheapest write boolean.

```
....   


  item.write({'cheapest': True})
else:
  item.write({'cheapest': False})
```

NB: I have set field quality to Boolean that's why in the end I am writting "True" or "False"

Or is there a better way to do it

Any help will be appreciated